# How to find a radius of a circle tangent to another circle and line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

[image: graph]

As in the image, I have a circle that intersect the $y$ axis (or could be a vertical line).
I know center and radius of that circle.
There is a second smaller circle, inside the bigger one, tangent to the $y$ axis (or vertical line) and to the bigger circle.
I know the coordinate $y_A$ where the smaller circle intersect the vertical line.
I have to calculate the radius of the smaller circle $r$.
I try to do it using trigonometry, but I found a solution to be iterate. I'm looking for a "direct" solution.

Comment: You can draw a triangle with the three corners being $(0,y_a), (x_a, y_a), (x_C,y_c)$. The edge lengths of the triangle are $r, R-r$ and $d=\sqrt{x_C^2 + (y_C-y_a)^2}$. Now you can perhaps solve something from that ...

Comment: Let $\ell$ be the vertical line $x=R$. Then the distance from $A$ to $\ell$ equals the distance from $A$ to $C$, that is, the locus of valid $A$ is on a parabola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the circle's centre will be at $(r,y_A)$. Then we have the following relation from the tangency with the larger circle:
$$\sqrt{(x_C-r)^2+(y_A-y_C)^2}=R-r$$
Let $(y_A-y_C)^2=K$, then squaring both sides:
$$(x_C-r)^2+K=R^2-2Rr+r^2$$
$$x_C^2-2x_Cr+K=R^2-2Rr$$
$$r(2R-2x_C)=R^2-x_C^2-K$$
$$r=\frac{R^2-x_C^2-K}{2R-2x_C}$$